# Compare two dictionaries keys and create dictionary with list values in Python

Tags: python

Let's say you have two different dictionaries.

```
info_stored = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 15}

log_stored = {'dog' : 1, 'a' : 1, 'ted' : 14}
```

I want to compare these 2 dictionaries to determine if keys are matched. Only 'a' is common in this example.

```
for key in info_stored:
    if key in log_stored:
```

I want to create a new dictionary with the common key and a list of the values from that common key.

```
common_stored = {'a' : [0, 1]}
```

Comment: You code almost done that. What's your problem? Since you can extract the dictionary key value and create a list .

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
info_stored = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 15}

log_stored = {'dog' : 1, 'a' : 1, 'ted' : 14}

common_stored = {k: [] for k in info_stored if k in log_stored}
```

and then:

```
for key in common_stored:
    common_stored[k].extend([info_stored[k], log_stored[k]])
print(common_stored)  # common_stored = {'a' : [0, 1]}
```

The first step is about creating a dictionary with the common elements as keys and empty lists as values.

Finally we modify these empty lists based on the contents of the original dicts.

**You can even combine the two steps in a single dictionary comprehension  as follows:**

```
common_stored = {k: [info_stored[k], log_stored[k]] for k in info_stored if k in log_stored}
```

Comment: That's it.  Thank you very much.  I found a solution for one variable, but I kept writing over my dictionary if there was another matching variable.  This make it look so easy, and I imagine it is for most.

Answer (score 1):

```
info_stored = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 15}
log_stored = {'dog' : 1, 'a' : 1, 'ted' : 14}

common_stored = {}

# Traverse through info_stored dictionary
for key, val in info_stored.items():
   # Check for key in log_stored dictionary, if found add it to common_stored
   if key in log_stored:
      common_stored[key] = [val, log_stored[key]]

common_stored
{'a': [0, 1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution would be this:

```
info_stored = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 15}

log_stored = {'dog' : 1, 'a' : 1, 'ted' : 14}

result={}


for key in info_stored :
  if key in log_stored :
    result[key]=[ info_stored[key], log_stored[key]]

print (result)
```